# CORS issue using Grape API and Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, heroku, cors

I have a read-only API and it works well locally with a Vagrant setup. Live on my Heroku app, every API request is denied due to a CORS error: "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

In my API's base class, I have the following to set the headers:

```
module API
  class Base < Grape::API
    before do
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, OPTIONS'
      headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
    end

    mount API::V1::Base   
  end
end
```

I suspect that this `before` call is not being fired—if I use a puts statement inside of it, that statement does not appear in my console with the rest of the output.

I am at a loss. Hopefully someone has some experience with this. Thank you.

**Edit:** I have also followed [Grape's CORS instructions](https://github.com/intridea/grape#cors) but get the same result.

**Success.** I used the [rack-cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) gem and the following:

```
#application.rb
config.middleware.use Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'

    # location of your API
    resource '/api/*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options, :put]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6):

You get Access-Control-Allow-Origin error every time you made a request.

This is probably because your server API does not respond to **OPTIONS** requests with the headers required for CORS.

You can check it in the development console -> network tab if you are using Google Chrome.

It's interesting that some Javascript frameworks do make an OPTIONS request before a normal request is sent to the server.

Solution:

1. Modify your Gemfile to include **'rack-cors'**.
2. Run **bundle install**
3. **Modify your config.ru**:

*if you get errors launching rails server, check your API namespace after 'run'

```
require 'rack/cors'

use Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :options, :put]
  end
end

run API::V1::Base
```

Now you should see Grape handles all OPTIONS requests with the CORS headers.

Comment: Yes, I had already posted the successful solution in my original post. Thanks.

Comment: Oh. I just realized my answer copied from grape docs didn't include the options method. It is updated now. ([:get, :post, :options, :put] instead of just :get)

Comment: Just note for rails framework, inside config.ru, add line `run API::V1::Base` before line `run Rails.application`